# Rails internationalization problem (korean)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

I'm using rails 2.3.10 and ruby 1.9.2

My problem can be put into these terms:

```
# ---------------------------
# SomeViewsController.rb
# ---------------------------
def index
  I18n.locale = :kr
  @news = News.new(:title => "추가", :body => "Place text here")
  @news.save
end
# --------------------------- 


# ---------------------------    
# some_views/index.html.erb
# ---------------------------
TITLE: <%= @news.title %>
# ---------------------------
```

My problem is on the I18n.locale part. When I set it to Korean (:kr), I get this error

> ActionView::TemplateError (incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT)

But when I set it to 'en', or the default, it displays the Korean characters just fine.

Please, can anybody enlighten me how this is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really know why, but when I switched the database.yml to use the adapter from mysql to mysql2, it started working. So, it's fine now. Thanks anyway. :)

Comment: Hi Odina, it would be great if you could mark your answer as correct so that people who might stumble upon it in the future will know that it works :)

Comment: @theIV Ok, got it. :) [It says in 2 days' time, I can accept my own answer. I'll mark it then]